# Debian's unattended upgrades and third party repositories

Tags: debian, repository, unattended

I have my system set up to perform automatic updates (unattended-upgrades), however, it doesn't work for third party repositories, I've installed Signal Desktop and I'm not receiving updates.

I'm aware that I need to add the appropriate piece of code to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`, I just can't figure out the syntax.

This is the relevant part of `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`:

```
DEBUG Checking: signal-desktop ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'xenial' origin:'. xenial' label:'. xenial' site:'updates.signal.org' isTrusted:True>])
```

I'm using Debian Stretch.

Comment: I don't think you need any special syntax. The file name is also irrelevant — the files under `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` are all sourced and have the same impact as if their contents would have been put directly into `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
So the sytnax you need is the same you'd use for that file: `deb URL suite section`.

Comment: You should first attempt to manually inspect if the package of interest is available by running `apt update` and then `apt-cache policy signal-desktop` (or whatever the name of the package is).